# Closing Service Cloud Case Milestones using Apex

Tags: apex, servicecloud, entitlements

I am having a look at `Case` milestones and entitlement processes that are part of the service cloud. I want to programmatically close one of the milestones after a certain `Status` value has been selected in the `Case` object, as suggested in the [Entitlements Best Practice](https://na9.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/entitlements_best_practices.htm) page.

> Use Apex code to automatically mark milestones as Completed on cases that match unique criteria. For example, you can create an Apex trigger on EmailMessage that marks a first response milestone as Completed on cases when support reps send email from cases.

However, when I wrote a trigger to attempt this I found out that the IsCompleted field of the CaseMilestone object seems to be unwritable. (I checked in workbench as well and it has `updateable : false` for the `IsCompleted` field)

How would I close the milestone as suggested in the best practices docs?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to populate the CaseMilestone record's CompletionDate that will make the IsCompleted field true.